# One repository for two Github organizations?

Tags: git, github, github-organizations

I was working on one repo that was assigned to one Github organization. Now organization is expanding and we created a "suborganization" or "satellite organization" and we want that a particular repository would be visible in both organizations.

Is that possible? Maybe repo can stay at one organization and other would only be a participant or would display repo with aliases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called mirroring here is a tutorial on how to do it on GitHub :
https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository